# SQL Server 2012 Express (x64) cannot upgrade the existing instance of SQL Server Express (x64 WoW) named 'SQLEXPRESS'

Tags: sql-server-2012, wow64

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express edition is already installed. I added SQL Server 2012 Express in Prerequisite in Windows Installer.

I'm getting this error while installing setup at start

> Can not install different instance. Required instance name as SQLEXPRESS.
>
> Prerequisite check for system component SQL Server 2012 Express failed with the following error message:
>   "SQL Server 2012 Express (x64) cannot upgrade the existing instance of SQL Server Express (x64 WoW) named 'SQLEXPRESS'.
>   Uninstall this instance of SQL Server Express and retry installing SQL Server 2012 Express (x64)."

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You try to give the name `SQLEXPRESS` to your second instance while there is already one (2005) instance on this pc with **the same instance name**.

What you need is just to give another name to the second instanse, for example `SQLEXPRESS_2012`, when install it

Comment: But I want instance name as SQLEXPRESS not SQLEXPRESS_2012. Is it not possible to upgrade?

Comment: If you want to upgrade, just upgrade it, not install the second instance.

Comment: >>>after upgrade also its giving same error<<< What does it mean "after"? The instance has been upgraded or not? And what is your full @@version of existing instance?

Comment: @Dev, please update your question with the result of SELECT @@VERSION on your existing instance. (x64 WoW) makes me think you are trying to upgrade x32 to x64 that is not possible

Comment: I have created instance with different , solved problem thanks